# JOIN - count from one table and sum form another

Tags: mysql, join

Example for demonstration:

tab_sellers:

```
id_seller | seller 
   1         John  
   2         Marie 
   3         Jamie 
   4         Arnold
   5         peter
```

tab_sales:

```
id | sales | seller | value
1     BMW       1      100
2     FORD      1      200
3     FIAT      2      300
4     FORD      2      400
5     FORD      3      400
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1- the sum (edited: is not sum, is COUNT) of the sellers from *seller* in *tab_sellers* and the total of their sales from *value* in *tab_sales*

Expected outcome:

```
total_sellers | total_value_sales
      5           14000
```

2- the sum (edited: is not sum, is COUNT) of the sellers who have sales and the total of their sales

Expected outcome:

```
total_sellers_with_sales | total_value_sales
         3                       14000
```

EDITED: An example of what I tried unsuccessfully

```
  SELECT COUNT(ts.seller) AS tab_sellers,
       COALESCE(SUM(tsl.value),0) AS total_value_sales
  FROM tab_sellers ts 
  LEFT JOIN tab_sales tsl ON ts.id_seller = tsl.seller
```

I get de correct sum but not the correct count

Comment: `sum of the sellers`? You mean `Count()` don't you?

Comment: I edited my post with correction and de code. Thanks WEI_DBA

Comment: @josei : you are very close to answer. All you need is `distinct` keyword in your count. Look at my answer below.

Comment: Of course. An essential detail. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try them but these 2 queries should answer you

```
Select count(distinct a.seller), sum(b.value)
from tab_sellers a 
left join tab_sales b
on a.id_seller = b.seller


Select count(distinct seller), sum(value)
from tab_sales
```

Comment: Thanks Prabhat G. The second query is a simple and a good idea.I will try to use it in my query (more complex than my example). I edited my post with the code I have tried so far

Comment: Yep, I believe your query will work with `distinct`. Happy learning !

Answer (score 1):

Both in one query:

```
select 
  count(distinct sel.id_seller) as sellers,
  count(distinct sal.seller) as sellers_with_sales,
  sum(sal.value) as total_value_sales
from tab_sellers sel 
left join tab_sales sal on sal.seller = sel.id_seller;
```

Comment: Tnanks Thorsten Kettner.